# SpringBoot absolute path clarification

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java.nio.file

I'm new to SpringBoot web dev.
I need to save an image to a directory in the current project. I have given path as "String uploaddir = "./src/main/imageuploads/"+ savedadvert.getId();" but the image not save to the "./src/main/imageuploads/" directory in eclipse project.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String FileUpload(@RequestParam("file1Url") MultipartFile multipartfile, Model model) throws IOException {
    
    model.addAttribute("advertsim",new advertsummary());
    
    advertsummary advert = new advertsummary();
      
    String file1Urlname= StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartfile.getOriginalFilename());
    advert.setFile1Url(file1Urlname);
                                               
    advertsummary savedadvert = AdvertService.addadvert(advert);
    
    String uploaddir = "./src/main/imageuploads/"+ savedadvert.getId(); 

    FileUploadUtil.saveFile(multipartfile, file1Urlname, uploaddir);    
    
    return "uploadview";
}
```

This is the saveFile method for ref.

```
public static void saveFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, String fileName, String uploadDir) throws IOException {
     Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadDir);
     
        if (!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
            Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
        }
          
        try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
            Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(fileName);
            System.out.println(filePath.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
            Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {       
            throw new IOException("Could not save image file: " + fileName, ioe);
        }
    
}
```

I need to upload the image to this directory,
[image]

when I get the absolute path, it shows like this "/Users/chathura/eclipse/jee-2021-03/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/./src/main/imageuploads/24/new file.jpg".
There is no way to go to this directory but I can access that directory using the terminal.

[image]

Please tell me what is the mistake here?

Note : I'm using macos

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use images, but actually add your code to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for that, I have added the code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Could you try 'src/main/resources/imagesuploads' (without .)
2. Just a reminder: This directory will disappear when you package your application (production mode)
3. This directory should be configurable from an external file (application. properties for example)

Comment: Hi Ali , It's showing,

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type  : Exception Report
Message : /src: Read-only file system
Description : The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
Exception : java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /src: Read-only file system

Comment: I guess this error is related to not writing into Root directory. how can I write file into a directory in Root?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ali, your response gave a lead to the solution. My project sits on MacOS partition therefore, I couldn't write a file without permission. I simply changed the location to another partition and it worked.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String FileUpload(@RequestParam("file1Url") MultipartFile multipartfile, Model model) throws IOException {
    
    model.addAttribute("advertsim",new advertsummary());
    
    advertsummary advert = new advertsummary();
      
    String file1Urlname= StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartfile.getOriginalFilename());
    advert.setFile1Url(file1Urlname);
                                               
    advertsummary savedadvert = AdvertService.addadvert(advert);
    
    String uploaddir = "/Volumes/My Data/Fileupload"+ savedadvert.getId();  

    FileUploadUtil.saveFile(multipartfile, file1Urlname, uploaddir);    
    
    return "uploadview";
}
```

Thank you